# How to set a subdomain under main domain on google search?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index

I have a site and a blog as subdomain. The both are indexed on google, however, when I search for my domain, the blog and site are displayed separately. I'd like to show them "aggregated" way.

For example, attached has the result of stackoverflow searching on google. The picture has the main site and under it, some pages as Questions, Jobs, Java, etc.

How can I set my blog under my main site?

Regards

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

those are called site links and are quto generated by google if links on your website are evaluated as important